# Can I guarantee state has changed before form has submitted?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Depending on whether the user 'approves' or 'declines', a different submit callback is required. As a result, I set the state variable 'submitCallBack' to the relevant function based on what the user clicked. The question I have is that **can I guarantee submitCallBack will be set or a re-render will occur BEFORE submit completes? (since setState is async)**

This is currently working as 'expected' but would like to ensure I won't have issues when releasing

The sequence of events I want to occur:

1. User clicks button
2. this.handleSubmit() is called with the callback
3. submitCallBack is set and the **form re-renders**
4. **submit event occurs** and the handleSubmit is set with the correct callback

```
class FormClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      submitCallBack: () => {}
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = callback => () => {
    // this needs to be set before the submit completes and the forms callback function 
    // for onSubmit must be set to this new value
    this.setState({ submitCallBack: callback })
  }

   render() {
    const { error, invalid, submitting, handleSubmit, approve, decline } = this.props
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.state.submitCallBack)}>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            onClick={this.handleSubmit(approve)}
            primary
            action
            loading={submitting}
          >
            Approve
          </Button>
          <Button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit(decline)}>
            Reject
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "submit completes"? What sequence of events do your expect of your code?

Comment: and what is the difference between `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(...)}>` and `onClick={**this**.handleSubmit(...)}`

Comment: @x00  The difference between those two is one is a class method (this) and the other is a prop passed in by redux-forms. What I want to ensure is that when onClick occurs, the `submitCallBack` is set FIRST, the form is re-rendered with the correct callback and then the form is submitted

Comment: Why don't you just make the callback call on the `handleSubmit` method? You don't need to do the function call on the form submission just when user clicks approve/decline you set the state and on the callback of set state you fire the parent `handleSubmit`. You wouldn't even need to use state with this (unless the component has more login). I don't know about the firing steps on these case but you can test your solution doing some timeout on the setState. a timeOut to begin the setState and a timeOut in the setState so through console.log you can check the order is things.